# Url redirection

Tags: node.js, redirect

what Im doing wrong in the below code

```
 var path = 'http://' + someip + ':' + port ;
 //var path = "http://someip:1000/";  // This is working
 res.writeHead(302, {'Location': path});
```

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: `var path = 'http://' + someip + port ;` does not output a string in the format `IP:PORT` as your hardcoded test does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to understand your problem just by two lines, you might be doing other things wrong. This should be what you looking for.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var someip = '127.0.0.1';
var port = '8080';

app.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  var path = 'http://' + someip + ':' + port ;
  body = 'Redirecting to ' + path;
  res.writeHead(302, {'Location': path, 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: @user87267867 May be this can help you